# Hibernate 3.6 : Schema Export fails, autocommit = false?

Tags: hibernate

Im reading the hibernate book about schema export:
http://jpa.ezhibernate.com/Javacode/learn.jsp?tutorial=02validatingthehibernateenvironment

I tried running the code in Hibernate 3.6, but the schema is not created, and assuming from the output log, perhaps it's not commited somehow. Here is the log output :

```
105 [main] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
118 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.6.0.Final
119 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
122 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
124 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
165 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
165 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
199 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
217 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
245 [main] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
291 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
295 [main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Running hbm2ddl schema export
295 [main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - exporting generated schema to database
297 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
297 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 20
297 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
306 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: org.postgresql.Driver at URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernate
306 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=sofco, password=****}
346 [main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - schema export complete
347 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - cleaning up connection pool: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernate
```

Here's my code :

```
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;


public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
        config.configure();
        new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);
    }
}
```

and here's my hibernate cfg xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

    <!--    MOHON DITAMBAHKAN SESUAI PACKAGE DAN URUT ABJAD -->

    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sofco</property>
        <property name="connection.password">kamalbert</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernate</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

I wonder what i am missing here ..

Regards,

Albert Kam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some things are missing from the logs, but it's probably because you didn't mark your entity with @Entity.

Comment: wow ! how did i miss that ! haha. It works fine now, thanks man. Although, creating table name user seems to be problematic in postgresql 9. After changing the classname to MstUser, it works fine. Here are the logs : drop table MstUser cascade ..
drop sequence hibernate_sequence ..
create table MstUser (id int8 not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id)) ..
create sequence hibernate_sequence ..
542 [main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - schema export complete ..

Comment: "User" is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL (and Oracle, probably). You don't need to change your class name (and you shouldn't). Just quote it, using @Entity(table="`user`").

Comment: I just found out about that annotation yesterday also.. Thanks ! :)